# Intel SGX - Remote attestation

Tags: man-in-the-middle, remote-attestation, intel-sgx

I am currently reading up on Intel's SGX, especially the remote attestation part. I am having a questions regarding this topic.

Let us consider the following protocol:

Enclave A and B do remote attestation. Each of them generates an asymmetric key pair (sk_X, pk_X). They exchange the quotes:

```
A -> B: QUOTE{pk_A}
B -> A: QUOTE{pk_B}
```

Let us consider there is a MitM attacker, who intercepts whose quotes and forwards them. Is it possible for the attacker to read out the public keys or are they somehow encrypted? I could not find proper information in the documentation.

---

I found the following document: [intel-sgx-developer-guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/33/70/intel-sgx-developer-guide.pdf)

> A quote includes the following data:
>
> - Measurement of the code and data in the enclave.
> - A hash of the public key in the ISV certificate presented at enclave initialization time.
> - The Product ID and the Security Version Number (SVN) of the enclave.
> - Attributes of the enclave, for example, whether the enclave is running in debug mode.
> - User data included by the enclave in the data portion of the report structure. Allows establishing a secure channel bound to the remote attestation process so a remote server may provision secrets to the entity that has been attested
> - A signature block over the above data, which is signed by the Intel EPID group key

It sounds like everyone would be able to read the data. In order to prevent a MitM attack, the enclaves have to verify the hash of the public key of the ISV (independent software vendor) and maybe the product ID.

Comment: Note that the question was also [asked and answered in an Intel forum](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-software-guard-extensions-intel-sgx/topic/754576).

Answer (score 1):

The article [Code Sample: Intel Software Guard Extensions Remote Attestation End-to-End Example](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/code-sample-intel-software-guard-extensions-remote-attestation-end-to-end-example) (by John M. from Intel), describes an example of remote attestation. (The source code of most of the functions described in the article can be found [here](https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx/blob/master/sdk/tkey_exchange/tkey_exchange.cpp).)

Among others, the article mentions the structure of the remote attestation quote, [`sgx_quote_t`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/sgx-sdk-dev-reference-sgx-quote-t):

> The structure of the quote is defined in [sgx_quote.h](https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx/blob/master/common/inc/sgx_quote.h):
>
> ```
> typedef struct _quote_t
> {
>     uint16_t            version;        /* 0   */
>     uint16_t            sign_type;      /* 2   */
>     sgx_epid_group_id_t epid_group_id;  /* 4   */
>     sgx_isv_svn_t       qe_svn;         /* 8   */
>     sgx_isv_svn_t       pce_svn;        /* 10  */
>     uint32_t            xeid;           /* 12  */
>     sgx_basename_t      basename;       /* 16  */
>     sgx_report_body_t   report_body;    /* 48  */
>     uint32_t            signature_len;  /* 432 */
>     uint8_t             signature[];    /* 436 */
> } sgx_quote_t;
> ```

One of the members of the struct [`sgx_report_body_t`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/sgx-sdk-dev-reference-sgx-report-body-t) (defined in [sgx_report.h](https://github.com/intel/linux-sgx/blob/master/common/inc/sgx_report.h)) is `report_data`, whose type is [`sgx_report_data_t`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/sgx-sdk-dev-reference-sgx-report-data-t).
`report_data` is the arbitrary information that an enclave can include inside its remote attestation quote. It is only 512 bits, so you would probably put there a hash of a public key (and send the public key itself alongside the quote).

Either way, if I understand correctly, `report_data` isn't encrypted by default.

Note that assuming the attacker cannot execute arbitrary code inside an enclave, they can't perform the classic MitM of a Diffie-Hellman key exchange (as described [here](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/91699/188882)), as they cannot create a quote with a valid signature.